# Spring batch - skip on MyException stop on all other Exception

Tags: java, spring-batch

Goal: if there is an AdmisSkipException (custom exception) I want the job to skip the record and keep on processing next lines.
If there is any other exception I want the job to stop.

Here is what I have so far:

Conf:

```
       .<Admis, PreCandidat>chunk(100)
       .reader(readerDBAdmis())
       .processor(new AdmisItemProcessor(preCandidatRepository, scolFormationSpecialisationRepository, preCandidatureRepository))
       .faultTolerant()
       .skipPolicy(AdmisVerificationSkipper())
       .writer(writerPGICocktail()).build();
```

AdmisSkipException :

```
public class AdmisSkipException extends Exception {
    private TypeRejet typeRejet;
    private Admis admis;

    public AdmisSkipException(TypeRejet typeRejet, Admis admis) {
        super();
        this.typeRejet = typeRejet;
        this.admis = admis;
    }

    public TypeRejet getTypeRejet() {
        return typeRejet;
    }

    public Admis getAdmis() {
        return admis;
    }
}
```

AdmisVerificationSkipper :

```
public class AdmisVerificationSkipper implements SkipPolicy {
    private AdmisRejetRepository admisRejetRepository;

    public AdmisVerificationSkipper(AdmisRejetRepository admisRejetRepository) {
        this.admisRejetRepository = admisRejetRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldSkip(Throwable exception, int skipCount) throws SkipLimitExceededException {
        if (exception instanceof AdmisSkipException) {
            AdmisSkipException admisSkipException = (AdmisSkipException) exception;
            AdmisRejet rejet = new AdmisRejet();
            rejet.setAdmis(admisSkipException.getAdmis());
            rejet.setTypeRejet(admisSkipException.getTypeRejet());
            admisRejetRepository.save(rejet);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

With this configuration, if a NullPointerException (for example) is thrown in AdmisItemProcessor, the job will continue instead of failing.
What should I change to stop the job ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if there is an AdmisSkipException (custom exception) I want the job to skip the record and keep on processing next lines. If there is any other exception I want the job to stop.

You can achieve this with:

```
   .<Admis, PreCandidat>chunk(100)
   .reader(readerDBAdmis())
   .processor(new AdmisItemProcessor(preCandidatRepository, scolFormationSpecialisationRepository, preCandidatureRepository))
   .writer(writerPGICocktail())
   .faultTolerant()
   .skip(AdmisSkipException.class)
   .skipLimit(SKIP_LIMIT) 
   .build();
```

Looking at your code, you probably had to create a custom skip policy because you want to save skipped items somewhere. I would recommend to use a `SkipListener` instead, which is designed specifically for this type of requirements. Having a `shouldSkip` method save items to a repository is a side effect. So this is better done with a listener. That said, you won't need a custom policy and `.skip(AdmisSkipException.class).skipLimit(SKIP_LIMIT)` should be enough.

> With this configuration, if a NullPointerException (for example) is thrown in AdmisItemProcessor, the job will continue instead of failing. What should I change to stop the job ?

Here is an example you can run to see how it works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution;
import org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameters;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.StepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemProcessor;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader;
import org.springframework.batch.item.ItemWriter;
import org.springframework.batch.item.support.ListItemReader;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.lang.Nullable;

@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class MyJob {

    @Autowired
    private JobBuilderFactory jobs;

    @Autowired
    private StepBuilderFactory steps;

    @Bean
    public ItemReader<Integer> itemReader() {
        return new ListItemReader<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10));
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer> itemProcessor() {
        return new ItemProcessor<Integer, Integer>() {
            @Nullable
            @Override
            public Integer process(Integer item) throws Exception {
                if (item.equals(3)) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("No 3!");
                }
                if (item.equals(9)) {
                    throw new NullPointerException("Boom at 9!");
                }
                return item;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<Integer> itemWriter() {
        return items -> {
            for (Integer item : items) {
                System.out.println("item = " + item);
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return steps.get("step")
                .<Integer, Integer>chunk(1)
                .reader(itemReader())
                .processor(itemProcessor())
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .faultTolerant()
                .skip(IllegalArgumentException.class)
                .skipLimit(3)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobs.get("job")
                .start(step())
                .build();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyJob.class);
        JobLauncher jobLauncher = context.getBean(JobLauncher.class);
        Job job = context.getBean(Job.class);
        JobExecution jobExecution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
        System.out.println(jobExecution);
    }

}
```

This example skips items when `IllegalArgumentException`s are thrown and fails the job if a `NullPointerException` happens.

Hope this helps.

Comment: "Looking at your code, you probably had to create a custom skip policy because you want to save skipped items somewhere. I would recommend to use a SkipListener instead" Yes, that is exactly what I want to do. I will change it to SkipListener.

Comment: If open another thread about Skip Listener here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52998908/how-to-skip-item-into-itemprocesslistener

Comment: There is a logging listener example here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#loggingItemProcessingAndFailures. You can do the same for skipped items by saving them to a repository instead of just logging them as in the sample.